# Binding directive from object to ng-repeat in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using a directive with ng-repeat, which looks like this:

```
<new-tax-country  
    ng-repeat="newItem in data.company.extraTaxCountries track by $index" 
    ng-model="data.company.extraTaxCountries[$index]"> 
</new-tax-country>
```

I'm adding objects in the array according to the need, like this:

```
$scope.addTaxCountry = function() {
   $scope.data.company.extraTaxCountries.push({});
}
```

On every click of the button, I'm adding a new empty object into the array, and also a new directive is created.

I need to bind the directive to the empty object, so that when I fill the fields inside the directive, those exist also in the previously empty object.

My directive so far looks like this:

```
(function() {

    angular.module('account-form-client-de')
        .directive("newTaxCountry", function(Countries) {
            var options = {
                restrict: 'E',
                require: 'ngModel',
                replace: true,
                scope: {
                    
                },
                link: function(scope, element, attrs, controller, $parent) {
                        
                    
                },
                templateUrl: 'template/directive/new-tax-country.html'
            };

            return options;
        });
})();
```

And the html:

```
<div class="newtaxcountry">
    <label for="new_taxid">
        bla
    </label>
    <input name="new_taxid" ng-model="newTaxInnerScope.new_taxid">
</div>
```

How could I proceed so that every `newItem in data.company.extraTaxCountries` automatically inherits the properties of the `newTaxInnerScope` object that exists inside the directive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set up a bidirectional binding in order to read and write back from within the inner directive to your variables.

I created a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/aemw7d29/1/

The main part is this:

```
angular.module('account-form-client-de')
    .directive("newTaxCountry", [function(Countries) {
        function link(scope, element, attrs, controller, $parent) {
            scope.ngModel.a = scope.ngModel.a ? scope.ngModel.a++ : 1;
        }
        
        var options = {
            restrict: 'E',
            require: 'ngModel',
            replace: true,
            scope: { ngModel : '=' },
            link: link,
            template: '<div class="newtaxcountry"><label for="new_taxid">bla</label><input name="new_taxid" ng-model="newTaxInnerScope.new_taxid">{{ngModel}}</div>'
        };

        return options;
    }]);
```

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but in your example, the `ng-model="newTaxInnerScope.new_taxid"` from the input is not bind to the `newItem`?

Comment: Oh, right I forgot something. Have a look at the updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/aemw7d29/2/ The names are changed a bit, but it should show how it will work.

Answer (score 1):

Though there is accepted answer, I'll leave it here...

First of all if you need simple input for directive -- never name it `ng-model` (also you dont need to require ngModel directive), just take any other name e.g. `country` here:

```
<new-tax-country
  ng-repeat="country in data.company.extraTaxCountries track by $index" 
  country="country">
</new-tax-country>


.directive("newTaxCountry", [function(Countries) {
    var options = {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope: { country : '=' },
        template: '<div class="newtaxcountry"><label for="new_taxid">bla</label><input name="new_taxid" ng-model="country.new_taxid"></div>'
    };
    
    return options;
}]);
```

You may want to use `ng-model` if you want to put this directive into some form and specify validators on it (not on underlined input element), then you require ngModelCtrl and work with it instead of scope binding.